# Heroku-like services for Scala?

Tags: scala, heroku

I love Heroku but I would prefer to develop in Scala rather than Ruby on Rails.

Does anyone know of any services like Heroku that work with Scala?

**UPDATE**: Heroku now officially supports Scala - see answers below for links

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of October 3rd 2011, Heroku officially supports Scala, Akka and sbt.

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/10/3/scala/

Answer (score 11):

**Update**

Heroku has just [announced](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/25/java/) support for Java.

**Update 2**

Heroku has just [announced](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/10/3/scala/) support for Scala

**Also**

Check out [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

> To deploy Java applications using
>   Elastic Beanstalk, you simply:
>
> - Create your application as you
>     normally would using any editor or IDE
>     (e.g. Eclipse).
> - Package your
>     deployable code into a standard Java
>     Web Application Archive (WAR file).
> - Upload your WAR file to Elastic
>     Beanstalk using the AWS Management
>     Console, the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse,
>     the web service APIs, or the Command
>     Line Tools.
> - Deploy your application.
>     Behind the scenes, Elastic Beanstalk
>     handles the provisioning of a load
>     balancer and the deployment of your
>     WAR file to one or more EC2 instances
>     running the Apache Tomcat application
>     server.
> - Within a few minutes you will
>     be able to access your application at
>     a customized URL (e.g.
>     http://myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/).
>
> Once an application is running,
>   Elastic Beanstalk provides several
>   management features such as:
>
> - Easily deploy new application versions
>     to running environments (or rollback
>     to a previous version).
> - Access
>     built-in CloudWatch monitoring metrics
>     such as average CPU utilization,
>     request count, and average latency.
> - Receive e-mail notifications through
>     Amazon Simple Notification Service
>     when application health changes or
>     application servers are added or
>     removed.
> - Access Tomcat server log
>     files without needing to login to the
>     application servers.
> - Quickly restart
>     the application servers on all EC2
>     instances with a single command.

Another strong contender is [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/).   One of the nice features of Cloud Foundry is the ability to have a local version of "the cloud" running on your laptop so you can deploy and test offline.

Answer (score 2):

I started working on the exact same thing as what you said a few weeks ago. I use Lift, which is a great framework and has a lot of potential, on top of Linux chroot environment.

I'm done with a demo version, but Linux chroot is not that stable (nor secure), so I'm now switching to FreeBSD jail on Amazon EC2, and hopefully it'll be done soon.
http://lifthub.net/

There are also other Java hosting environment including VMForce mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a custom setup which also has the ease of deployment that heroku offers: http://dotcloud.com. They are invite only right now but I was given access in under three days. I am working on a Lift/MongoDB project there and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, only [VMForce](http://www.vmforce.com) comes to mind, but its not available yet. This will be a Java-oriented service, so that probably means you'll have to spend a wee bit of time figuring out how to package the app.

For more discussion, there was a [debate about this in 2008](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Developing-Scala-web-apps-on-the-web-td2006159.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if it's really suitable or not, but people have deployed Scala applications to Google App Engine, for example http://mawson.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/first-steps-with-scala-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can run scala on heroku right now. You don't believe it?

https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-playframework-scala

I'm not sure the tricks lstoll has used are legit but using the 
new cedar platform where you can run custom processes and some
ingenious Gemfile hacking he has managed to bootstrap the Java
play platform into a process. Seems to work as he has a live
site running a test page.

Comment: Rumor has it that Scala will receive first-class support on the Heroku stack soon.

Answer (score 0):

[Stax cloud service](http://stax.net/) offers preconfigured lift project skeleton. Also, there is a [tutorial](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/8193eb25e5a8b505/752aa89273043c85) on how to deploy lift project to appengine.